# How to select a value from one table and use it for another selection?

Tags: sql

I have 2 Tables, f.e.:

**Usertable:** name, surname, user_id,...

**Objecttable:** userID, date, object_id,...

Now I want to use the given variables `Object.ID` and `Object.Releasedate` to select userID from Objecttable where date = Object.Releasedate and object_id = Object.ID. Next, the selected userID should be used to select name, surname from Usertable where user_id = userID.

How do I write this in one Statement?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `inner join`

```
select name, surname
from usertable a inner join objecttable b
on a.user_id=b.userID
where date = Object.Releasedate and object_id = Object.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative  to the inner join is the subquery

```
select ut.name, ut.surname 
from Usertable ut 
where ut.user_id in (select ot.userID 
                     from Objecttable ot 
                     where ot.date = Object.Releasedate and
                           ot.object_id = Object.ID
                    );
```

Which one is better depends on your data structure, if you want to know, check the explain plan.

Comment: @Biome . . . I think this is the better solution.  First, it does not return duplicates if more than one row matches in the object table.  Second, it is better written, using proper table aliases and qualifying the column names.

Comment: Subquery is sometimes hard to debug